# Как преобразовать массив со строкой в массив с числом?

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная (строка) с координатами `var coor = "53.721923,91.430053"`.

Эта переменная попадает в массив `[coor]`. Соответственно массив выглядит так `["53.721923,91.430053"]`, но нужно получить массив с двумя числами `[53.721923,91.430053]`.

Как убрать кавычки из массива?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - разбивает объект `String` на массив строк путём разделения строки указанной подстрокой.

[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) -  принимает строку в качестве аргумента и возвращает десятичное число (число с плавающей точкой)

Думаю как из этого сделать  преобразование расписывать не надо

Comment: минусаторы ожидают что тут весь код чтоли напишут за автора?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
"53.721923,91.430053".split(",").map(v => parseFloat(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

**C#**

```
var numbers = coor.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

**JS**

```
var myArray = coor.split(",");
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) { myArray[i] = +myArray[i]; }
```

***P.S.***

*не заметил сразу метку JavaScript*

Comment: ты метку с языком не заметил?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, не заметил. уже исправил.

Comment: ок. снял минус.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо :)